# IIF to Case translation

Tags: sql, ms-access

Ok, So i need to convert a query that was originally used on an access database into a query that will run on a SQL-Compact Edition database.

and within that query I had an IIF statement (which doesn't work in sql)

Everything I've looked up suggests that i should replace it with Case When.

**This is my original code:**

```
Select [OrderNumber], [CustomerName], [PO_TAG], [Shape], [Size], [DrawingNumber],
[OrderBuildTime], [RequiredDateTime], [LatestStatusTime], [ExpectedCompletionDateTime],
[DateImported],  Sum(IIF([Status] = 'Printed', PanelBuildTime, 0)) AS OrderBuildTimee from 
SteelOrders 
INNER JOIN FinalizedPrintedStickers 
ON 
SteelOrders.OrderNumber = LEFT(FinalizedPrintedStickers.SN,10)
GROUP BY SteelOrders.OrderNumber, [CustomerName], [PO_TAG], [Shape], [Size], [DrawingNumber], 
[OrderBuildTime], [RequiredDateTime], [LatestStatusTime], [ExpectedCompletionDateTime], 
[DateImported]
```

**This is the IIF statement:**

```
Sum(IIF([Status] = 'Printed', PanelBuildTime, 0)) AS OrderBuildTimee
```

**This is what i replaced the IIF statement with:**

```
Sum(CASE Status WHEN 'Printed' THEN PanelBuildTime ELSE 0) AS OrderBuildTimee
```

**This is what the full body of code looks like afterwords:**

```
Select [OrderNumber],
[CustomerName],
[PO_TAG],
[Shape],
[Size],
[DrawingNumber],
[OrderBuildTime],
[RequiredDateTime],
[LatestStatusTime],
[ExpectedCompletionDateTime],
[DateImported],
Sum(CASE Status WHEN 'Printed' THEN PanelBuildTime ELSE 0) AS OrderBuildTimee 
From SteelOrders 
INNER JOIN FinalizedPrintedStickers 
ON 
SteelOrders.OrderNumber = LEFT(FinalizedPrintedStickers.SN,10)
GROUP BY SteelOrders.OrderNumber, [CustomerName], [PO_TAG], [Shape], [Size], [DrawingNumber], 
[OrderBuildTime], [RequiredDateTime], [LatestStatusTime], [ExpectedCompletionDateTime], 
[DateImported]
```

**And this is my new error message:**

```
Major Error 0x80040E14, Minor Error 25501
> Select [OrderNumber],
[CustomerName],
[PO_TAG],
[Shape],
[Size],
[DrawingNumber],
[OrderBuildTime],
[RequiredDateTime],
[LatestStatusTime],
[ExpectedCompletionDateTime],
[DateImported],
Sum(CASE Status WHEN 'Printed' THEN PanelBuildTime ELSE 0) AS OrderBuildTimee 
From SteelOrders 
INNER JOIN FinalizedPrintedStickers 
ON 
SteelOrders.OrderNumber = LEFT(FinalizedPrintedStickers.SN,10)
GROUP BY SteelOrders.OrderNumber, [CustomerName], [PO_TAG], [Shape], [Size], [DrawingNumber], 
[OrderBuildTime], [RequiredDateTime], [LatestStatusTime], [ExpectedCompletionDateTime], 
[DateImported]
There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 12,Token line offset = 58,Token in 
error = ) ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper syntax for a `CASE` is:

```
Simple CASE expression: 
CASE input_expression 
     WHEN when_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ] 
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ] 
END 

Searched CASE expression:
CASE
     WHEN Boolean_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ] 
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ] 
END
```

In your query you are missing the `END` for the CASE:

```
Sum(CASE Status WHEN 'Printed' THEN PanelBuildTime ELSE 0 END) AS OrderBuildTimee
```

So the full code is:

```
Select [OrderNumber],
  [CustomerName],
  [PO_TAG],
  [Shape],
  [Size],
  [DrawingNumber],
  [OrderBuildTime],
  [RequiredDateTime],
  [LatestStatusTime],
  [ExpectedCompletionDateTime],
  [DateImported],
  Sum(CASE Status WHEN 'Printed' THEN PanelBuildTime ELSE 0 END) AS OrderBuildTimee 
From SteelOrders 
INNER JOIN FinalizedPrintedStickers 
  -- left not supported by sql server ce use substring
  -- ON SteelOrders.OrderNumber = LEFT(FinalizedPrintedStickers.SN,10)
  ON SteelOrders.OrderNumber = substring(FinalizedPrintedStickers.SN, 1, 10)
GROUP BY SteelOrders.OrderNumber, [CustomerName], [PO_TAG], [Shape], [Size], [DrawingNumber], 
[OrderBuildTime], [RequiredDateTime], [LatestStatusTime], [ExpectedCompletionDateTime], 
[DateImported]
```

Comment: yay, Except i get a new error message because LEFT isn't supported in sqlcompact -_- . Oh well I'll just replace it with substring